# Rewrite condition only running the first one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

staging.domain.com should go to domain.com/blog (last rule) but it goes to domain.com
staging.domain.com/category/food should go to domain.com/blog/category/food

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.domain.com/category [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.domain.com/work/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/#work [R=301,NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog [R=301,NC]
```

How do I make multiple rules, or am I chaining them wrong

Answer (score 1):

The variable `%{HTTP_HOST}` only contains the [HTTP request header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars). The URL part is not available to this variable. Therefore, the rules would have to be changed as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!work/?).*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/work/? [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/#work [R=301,NC]
```